# how to run main in jenkins job (mvn java)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

trying to run a mvn project with jenkins job.
i dont have test om my project, just a main with a little bit prints and functions.

i want to run it but i see that the job is skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/create_pass_criteria/src/test/resources

it is tring to run tests.

in the /src/ file i have just a main that i want to run, no test.
what i need to specify to run the main?

this is part of my jenkinFile :

```
stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn verify'
                sh 'mvn clean deploy'
            }
        }
```

is it enough to run main?

Comment: Sorry, but it is pretty unusual to run a main method during a build. Why not just write a proper test with JUnit?

Comment: BTW: It does not make sense to first run `mvn verify` and then `mvn clean deploy` because the latter already includes the former.

Comment: i dont use JUnit because i dont run tests.

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to run a `main` method on Jenkins?

Comment: i have a main class and another class. i need the main to create an object of my class and run its methods. so my program starts with the main.  Jenkins can't run main?

Comment: Jenkins is meant to **build** artifacts, not run them. Of course, you can also run them, but why do you want to? What does your main method do?

Comment: This code receives file input And adds a new test to another project. this is a device that gives the ability to run a code whenever there is a need to add test. the job should run my code not just build it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237095/discussion-between-orly-orly-and-j-fabian-meier).

Comment: Tests should be done as a unit tests or maybe integration tests which has to be defined as `src/test/java/<package>/XYZTest.java` where you implement your tests...never via a main...

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess this is meant as some kind of "script", i.e. it should be built and run to modify other projects. Something that is usually done by a bash script, or a Maven plugin or maybe a Jenkins plugin.